# Is there a way to flatten inherited jinja template?

Tags: inheritance, jinja2, webapp2, vulcanize

I have jinja templates that inherits from a base template.  Just straightforward extend.

For example, in setting.html:

```
{% extends "templates/base.html" %}
```

But this trips up polymer's vulcanizer, which doesn't understand the inheritance.  So, is there a way to "flatten" my setting.html first, i.e. pull in the base.html into setting.html, and without evaluating the variables?

I looked at [jinja's template api](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#high-level-api), but it's not very clear what api might do this?  The only one that looks close might be compile_templates()?  But again it's not clear from the documentation what this is really doing.

```
compile_templates(target, extensions=None, filter_func=None, zip='deflated', log_function=None, ignore_errors=True, py_compile=False)
```